# Take the position of the indexes that meets a condiion

Tags: python, list, date, if-statement

I have two lists,

In the first list I have all the information:

```
list1 = ['node1=6d', 'node2=10d', 'node3=5d']
```

In the second I just have the days:

```
list 2 = [6, 10, 5]
```

Is there a way to take the position from the indexes of the second one, that are <=7 ? (For example) and then print those with the same position of the list1?

Example:

Values of list2 that are <= 7:

```
Position 0, 2
```

Then print from list one those values with the position 0, 2

Output should be:

```
['node1=6d', 'node3=5d']
```

Comment: or perhaps `[v for i, v in enumerate(list1) if list2[i] <= 7]`

Comment: @komatiraju032 It would be worth you posting your `zip` version as an answer. It is simpler and more readable than the `itemgetter` approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original answer:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

idx = [i for i, n in enumerate(list2) if n <= 7]
result = itemgetter(*idx)(list1)

print(result)
```

---

To get the list item indices according to a condition, you can just use a list comprehension:

```py
idx = [i for i, n in enumerate(list2) if n <= 7]
```

If you wish to retrieve the values using the indices, you have several options, some of which are:

- Using `itemgetter`:

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the operand’s **getitem**() method. If multiple items are specified, returns a tuple of lookup values.
> [[Python Documentation]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```py
from operator import itemgetter

result = itemgetter(*idx)(list1)

print(result)
```

```
('node1=6d', 'node3=5d')
```

- Using a list comprehension again:

```py
result = [list1[i] for i in idx]
```

- Directly invoking `__getitem__` (This is not a best practice!):

> Called to implement evaluation of self[key]...
> [[Python Documentation]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

```py
result = list(map(list1.__getitem__, idx))
```

- **Bonus:** If you wish to use `numpy` at some point, this would be a convenient solution:

```py
import numpy as np

# Creating numpy arrays
list1 = np.array(['node1=6d', 'node2=10d', 'node3=5d'])
list2 = np.array([6, 10, 5])

# Getting the indices
idx = np.where(list2 <= 7)

# Getting all the values at once and converting the array into a list
result = list(list1[idx])
```

Comment: @jmgalan If you don't need to store indices in a separate variable, you can just use `zip()` just like in the answer of @komatiraju032 which is much more simple. The only reason I used this approach was because I thought you needed the indices and the values as separate lists (for printing etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
days_condition = 7
index_output = [index for index,val in enumerate(list_2) if val<=days_condition]

"Positions: "+",".join(map(str, index_output))

## you can access the list1 using the index_output
[list1[index] for index in index_output]
```

output:

```
'Positions 0,2'
['node1=6d', 'node3=5d']
```

Comment: output should be elements of first list

Comment: Nice, it works for taking all the positions, But... to print those values from the list1?

Comment: @komatiraju032, Yes He has parsed the first list to just `days`. I've updated the solution

Comment: @jmgalan, Please upvote if my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()`

```
res = [x for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if y < 8]
print(res)
#['node1=6d', 'node3=5d']
```